# Why TextInputLayout color is not changing if I put it in the AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I have tried to change the TextInputLayout color and it works perfectly, but once I put it in a AppBarLayout it not changes.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/weightText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/weight"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: As you can see the TextInputLayout is the same color as the AppBarLayout, nut it should be white.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's just a mistake of the Android Studio preview, on the Emulator works perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

i am using like this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="220dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"    //use any color here
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/green"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text">
```

**add this line in TextInputLayout**

app:hintTextAppearance="@style/mytext"

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/weightText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

**style xml code:**

```
<style name="text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red</item>
```

i hope it helps you.